# Python cluster module confusing class methods

Tags: python, class

I was trying to write a module for clustering, but class method are a little confusing for me

```
import numpy as np

class SingleLinkage:

    def __init__(self, x, k):
        self.data = x
        n=x.shape[0]
        self.clusters={i : [i] for i in range(n)}
        self.k=k
        self.y=None

    def euc(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        if self.y==None:
            self.y=y 
        return np.sqrt(np.sum((x-y)**2))

    def clustDist(self, i, j):
        cd=np.Inf
        for idx in self.clusters[i]:
            for idy in self.clusters[j]:
                cd=min(cd,self.euc(self.data[idx], self.data[idy]))
        return cd

    def findClothest(self):
        cd=np.Inf
        for i in self.clusters:
            for j in self.clusters:
                if i!=j and clustDist(i,j)<cd:
                    cc=(i,j)
                    cd=clustDist(i,j)
    def merge(self,i,j):
        self.clusters[i]+=self.clusters[j]
        self.clusters.pop(j)
```

When I run it, it gives me:

```
>>> x = np.array ([[0 , 0] , [0 , 0.1] , [1 , 1]])
>>> hc = lc.SingleLinkage (x , 2)
>>> hc.clusters
{0: [0], 1: [1], 2: [2]}
```

But should be different:

```
>>> hc.clusters
{0: [0 , 1] , 1: [2]}
```

I know that probably the error is in the init function. How should I  change it?

Comment: Please explain how/why the expected result should be `{0: [0, 1], 1: [2]}`.

Comment: 0 and 1 are two clusters based on euclidean distances

Comment: OK.  Does `x` represent an array of three 2D points?  What is `k`?

Comment: X is an n-by-m NumPy array(X represents
a set of n points in R), k is a number of clusters we want. Every cluster is represented as the list
of the indices of the points in the cluster.

Comment: The only place you use k as it is, is when it is set. Nowhere does it get used to make sure you only have k clusters. self.clusters={i : [i] for i in range(n)} literally just makes clusters a dict where the keys are 0 - n, and the values are a list containing the key. Are you expecting euc, clustDist, findClothest, or merge to be run or is that for a latter part of the program, because right now they are not being used.

Comment: In teory, this is all one function which should use all functions inside it to find clusters